# What could we do with a prophecies that are always the *opposite* of the future?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, alternate-reality, prophecy

In this world, the descendants of the various Oracles of Delphi have developed the ability to prophesy/predict the future.  However, rather than predict correctly, each one of these descendants predicts the *opposite* of what will happen.  These predictions are some degree of different from the events that generally occur.  If the prophecy is "X will not happen," then X *does* happen.

However, if the prophecy is that "Y will happen," there's no guarantee of the exact way in which Y will not occur.

The Daughters of Delphi are not many in number, and not well known -- but both the Big Bad and the protagonist are trying to use their predictions to respectively further / attempt to thwart the Big Bad's nefarious schemes.  It is not known whether the Daughters' predictions are connected to the futures that may have happened in an alternate universe or a timeline that is opposite ours, but the anti-predictions are the consistent result.

Question is, as these Daughters of Delphi are essentially anti-seers, what could either the good or the bad guys do with their predictions?

Comment: Depends how specific the prediction is. The majority of anti-predictions are going to be so vague that they are very unhelpful.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, this question is about your story and characters, not about your world, and is, as such, [off-topic for Worldbuilding SE](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened).

Comment: Possibly try Riddle Stack Exchange?

Comment: @HadesHerald [puzzling.se] rather than riddle.SE ?

Comment: @Käty, this is very open-ended, and plot-related question. It is unfortunately not the most suited for the format. I'd recommend reading the [tour] and perusing the [help] to be more familiar with it. Once you get enough reputation, you could join the [chat], where you would have some opportunity to discuss these kind of questions.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin ... Yes, I may need sleep now...

Comment: How is this off topic, please?

I personally see it as almost wholly without merit but so are half the Questions Posted in Worldbuilding.

How is this off topic, please?

Answer (score 3):

**Same as you would a normal prophecy**

If you know the seers are in fact anti-seers, then you can easily convert their anti-prophecies into normal prophecies by using the not logic operator.  For example:

> You are going to die on March 20th
>
> Villain is not going to destroy the hero's home city of Aliahan

Add a not operator to it and you get the actual prophecy:

> You are **not** going to die on March 20th
>
> Villain is **not** not going to destroy the hero's home city of Aliahan

Remove any double negatives and then at that point the prophecy is as useful or useless as any other prophecy and you can manipulate/abuse it as you want.

Comment: This isn't that useful though, a prophecy saying I will die on 20th March means I know I won't die until then. A prophecy saying I won't die on 20th March means I could die before or after that date.

Comment: But in this case the original prophecy would have been "You are not going to die on March 20th."  Who said the original prophecy would be any better than the anti prophecy?  Also note there was no year, so either way it is not a very useful prophecy.

Comment: @Bellerophon how useful that prophecy is depends on what you are doing on March 20th. Knowing, that no matter what happens--you will not die on that day. Sure, you could die from your injuries the very next day, but when you wake up on March 20th, every year, you'll know: today is not the day you die. For protagonist types, hey, this is fuel for the plot!

Comment: @Erin Thursby, that is fascinating!!  I hadn't thought of that angle; I was caught up on how unhelpful it would be to *not* know the rest of the story.  Hooray for plot fuel!!

Answer (score 2):

If you accept their ability to predict the future at face value, the original oracles were in the form of [riddles or vague statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oracular_statements_from_Delphi#circa_550_BC) anyways. If you read through those stories, it is always a matter of interpretation. The wise and heroic (Lycurgus, Leonidas, Phillip of Macedon) interpreted correctly, but the foolish and soon-to-be-defeated interpreted incorrectly (Croesus, Lysander).

This is the literary or mythological conceit of the oracles, so why would it have to change just because the answers are 'wrong'? In your writing you can have the statements be negative and vague, and have the heroes interpret correctly, and the losers interpret incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that this type of prophecy has little face value at first glance, with a little bit of logic they might actually spawn very powerful predictions:

> You shall fail with your plan

My plan will succeed. Do go on.

> Your foes will kill you on January 3rd.

So my foes will not kill me on that day. Nice. No need to take care of that... but what about my allies? Someone might betray me. Or there could be friendly fire. Or an accident. So better go alone that day.

In a way, for your plot, these predictions are FAR BETTER than normal predictions, since they can be true 100% of the time, but are not inevitable, giving your character some leeway and freedom to actually escape a dire situation.

Let's assume you have a 100% correct oracle. And it tells you:

> You will be killed by Jacob on January 3rd.

Now you are f*****d. you will die that day. Period. Jacob will kill you. No escaping, no changing, no way to save your character, unless you make the oracle be wrong. So story wise, your oracle can hardly make any serious, grave prediction or you will have to break your internal world consistency.

But, with your 100% wrong oracle:

> You will be killed by Jacob on January 3rd

It might give you a hint that your death is imminent. Maybe Jacob even has something to do with it. But on which day? Or is it Jacob? Or Max? Or does the prediction have absolutely nothing to do with the future? You now have some narrative freedom to save your character, and to change things. As long he isn't killed by Jacob on that specific date.

To be fair, you should have your predictions have something to do with the future. Otherwise, there will be bazillions of predictions that have absolutely no face value. For example because noone actually plans or tries to kill the character at all, his death not being a topic in the first place. So if a prediction about someones death comes up, the death of that person should be "possible", but just not in the given way.

Also, usually predictions are more useful if they are specific. In your case, your predictions become more useful the LESS specific they are.

> You will be killed by Jacob with a rifle on january 3rd

is much less useful than

> You will be killed by Jacob on January 3rd

is still less useful than

> you will be killed on january 3rd

and less useful than

> You will die this year.

I'd like to have the following please:

> You will die before January 1st 2060